# $C' = \{ a \in G : (ax)^2 = (xa)^2 \text{ } \forall x \in G \}. \text{Prove that } C' \text{ is a subgroup of } G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

(i) $(ex)^2 = x^2 = (xe)^2$ so that $e \in C'$.  $C'$ is non-empty.

(ii) Suppose $a,b \in C'$, then $(ax)^2 = (xa)^2$ and $(bx)^2 = (xb)^2$.  Need to prove $(abx)^2 = (xab)^2$ so that $(ab) \in C'$.

(iii) Let $a \in C'$, then $(ax)^2 = (xa)^2$.  Need to prove $(a^{-1}x)^2 = (xa^{-1})^2$ so that $a^{-1} \in C'$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(abx)^2 =(a(bx))^2 = (bxa)^2 = (b(xa))^2 = (xab)^2$$

Comment: Great!  So the trick was to group $bx$ and notice that $bx \in C'$, so it also commutes.  Any hints for how to approach (iii)?

Comment: $(a^{-1} x)^2 = ((x^{-1} a)^2)^{-1} \ldots$.

Comment: And no, $bx \notin C'$.  $(a(bx))^2 = ((bx)a)^2$ because $a \in C'$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction!  I had to stare at your hint and play with it for like 30 minutes, but I think I know what you mean now.  In that form, I can say $((x^{-1}a)^2)^{-1} = ((ax^{-1})^2)^{-1}$ because $a \in C'$, and everything follows.  The insight for the hint is just brilliant.  I learned a lot working through this problem (with your hints at just the right level) - thx again.